# PUZZLE TROUBLE - trying to save initial board

Tags: javascript, scope

I wrote this Javascript application for a 15-puzzle.  The entire application is contained in the file below.  Whenever I render a new board, I'm trying to store the initial configuration in the `initialBoard` variable so I can replay the same game later.  However, `initialBoard` variable always seems to equal the `currentBoard` variable.  I'm new to Javascript and any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>15 Puzzle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #puzzle-board {
            border: 5px solid;
        }
        .puzzle-tile {
            background:#fff;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #eee);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0, 0 100%, from(#fff), to(#eee));
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
            -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff;
            font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:60px;
            height: 100px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-shadow:0 1px #fff;
            user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            vertical-align:middle;
            width: 100px;
        }

        #start-stop {
            float: left;
        }

        #timer {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        #counter {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <br />
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                <table id="puzzle"></table>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="start-stop">START</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="timer"></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="counter"></button>
                </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        /**
         *  Puzzle Object
         */
        puzzle = function(targetId) {

            /************************************************************
             * Private members
             ************************************************************/

            var
                currentBoard,
                initialBoard,
                orderedBoard = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,'']];

            function canSwapTiles(source, target) {
                var sourceTileRow = source.attr("data-row");
                var sourceTileCol = source.attr("data-col");
                var sourceTileValue = source.text();

                var targetTileRow = target.attr("data-row");
                var targetTileCol = target.attr("data-col");
                var targetTileValue = target.text();

                if (sourceTileValue != '' && targetTileValue != '') {
                    return false;
                } else if (Math.abs(targetTileRow - sourceTileRow) > 1) {
                    return false;
                } else if (Math.abs(targetTileCol - sourceTileCol) > 1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            function swapTiles(source, target) {
                var sourceTileRow = source.attr("data-row");
                var sourceTileCol = source.attr("data-col");
                var sourceTileValue = source.text();

                var targetTileRow = target.attr("data-row");
                var targetTileCol = target.attr("data-col");
                var targetTileValue = target.text();

                source.text(targetTileValue);
                currentBoard[sourceTileRow][sourceTileCol] = parseInt(targetTileValue);

                target.text(sourceTileValue);
                currentBoard[targetTileRow][targetTileCol] = parseInt(sourceTileValue);

                $(targetId).trigger('moved');

                console.log("swapped tiles");
                console.log(initialBoard);

                if (isSolved())
                {
                    console.log('solved puzzle');
                    console.log(initialBoard);

                    $(targetId).trigger('solved', {
                        board: initialBoard
                    });
                }
            }

            function renderBoard(board) {
                $("#puzzle-board").empty();
                currentBoard = board;
                //initialBoard = board;

                console.log('rendering board');
                console.log(initialBoard);

                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    $("#puzzle-board").append('<tr class="puzzle-row" id="puzzle-row-' + i + '"></tr><br />');
                    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        var tile = '<td class="puzzle-tile" data-row="' + i + '" data-col="' + j + '">' +
                                board[i][j] +
                                '</td>';
                        $("#puzzle-row-" + i).append(tile);
                    }
                }

                $(".puzzle-tile").draggable(
                    {
                        revert: true,
                        snap: true,
                        snapMode: "inner",
                        zIndex: 100
                    }
                ).droppable(
                    {
                        drop: function (event, ui) {
                            var sourceTile = ui.draggable;
                            var targetTile = $(this);

                            if (canSwapTiles(sourceTile, targetTile)) {
                                swapTiles(sourceTile, targetTile);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }

            function randomBoard() {
                var tileValues = [];
                for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                    tileValues[i] = i + 1;
                }

                var randomlyOrderedTileValues = [''];
                do {
                    randomlyOrderedTileValues[(16 - tileValues.length)] = tileValues.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * tileValues.length), 1).pop();
                } while (tileValues.length > 0);

                var board = [];
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    board[i] = [];
                    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        board[i][j] = randomlyOrderedTileValues.pop();
                    }
                }
                return board;
            }

            function isSolved() {
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                        if (isNaN(currentBoard[i][j]))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (parseInt(currentBoard[i][j]) != parseInt(orderedBoard[i][j]))
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

            /************************************************************
             * Constructor
             ************************************************************/

            /*
             * Initialize board
             */
            $(targetId).append('<tbody id="puzzle-board"></tbody>');
            renderBoard(orderedBoard);

            /************************************************************
             * Public data and methods
             ************************************************************/

            return {
                reset: function() {
                    renderBoard(orderedBoard);
                },

                shuffle: function() {
                    //initialBoard = randomBoard();
                    initialBoard = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,'',15]];
                    renderBoard(initialBoard);
                }
            }
        };

        /**
         *  Timer Object
         */
        timer = function(targetId) {

            /************************************************************
             * Private members
             ************************************************************/

            var
                intervalId,
                totalSeconds = 0;

            function pad(val) {
                var valString = val + "";
                if (valString.length < 2) {
                    return "0" + valString;
                } else {
                    return valString;
                }
            }

            function setTime()
            {
                ++totalSeconds;
                $("#seconds").html(pad(totalSeconds % 60));
                $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60)));
            }

            /************************************************************
             * Constructor
             ************************************************************/

            /*
             * Initialize timer
             */
            $(targetId).append('<i>Time: &nbsp;</i><i id="minutes">00</i>:<i id="seconds">00</i>');

            /************************************************************
             * Public data and methods
             ************************************************************/

            return {
                reset: function() {
                    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
                    totalSeconds = 0;
                    $("#minutes").text('00');
                    $("#seconds").text('00');
                },

                start: function () {
                    intervalId = window.setInterval(setTime, 1000);
                },

                getTime: function () {
                    return pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60)) + ':' + pad(totalSeconds % 60);
                }
            }
        };

        /**
         *  Counter Object
         */
        counter = function(targetId) {

            /************************************************************
             * Private members
             ************************************************************/

            var
                steps = 0;

            /************************************************************
             * Constructor
             ************************************************************/

            /*
             * Initialize timer
             */
            $(targetId).append('<i id="steps-title">Steps: &nbsp;</i><i id="steps-count">0</i>');

            /************************************************************
             * Public data and methods
             ************************************************************/

            return {
                reset: function() {
                    steps = 0;
                    $("#steps-count").text(steps);
                },

                incr: function () {
                    steps++;
                    $("#steps-count").text(steps);
                },

                getSteps: function () {
                    return steps;
                }
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var Puzzle  = puzzle("#puzzle");
            var Timer   = timer("#timer");
            var Counter = counter("#counter");

            localStorage["games"] = '[]';

            $("#start-stop").click(function() {
                switch ($(this).text()) {
                    case 'START':
                        $(this).removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger").text("STOP");
                        Puzzle.shuffle();
                        Timer.start();
                        Counter.reset();
                        break;
                    case 'STOP':
                        $(this).removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success").text("START");
                        Puzzle.reset();
                        Timer.reset();
                        Counter.reset();
                        break;
                }
            });

            $("#puzzle").bind('moved',
                function(e, data) {
                    Counter.incr();
                }
            ).bind('solved',
                function(e, data) {

                    console.log(data);
                    
                    $("#start-stop").removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success").text("START");
                    Puzzle.reset();
                    Timer.reset();
                    Counter.reset();
                    
                }
            );
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: It's not fair to delete a question after someone's devoted time and effort answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke the Puzzle.shuffle() here:

```
$("#start-stop").click(function() {
    switch ($(this).text()) {
        case 'START':
            $(this).removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger").text("STOP");
            Puzzle.shuffle();
            Timer.start();
            Counter.reset();
            break;
        case 'STOP':
            $(this).removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success").text("START");
            Puzzle.reset();
            Timer.reset();
            Counter.reset();
            break;
    }
});
```

It initializes the board and passes it to renderBoard here

```
shuffle: function() {
    //initialBoard = randomBoard();
    initialBoard = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,'',15]];
    renderBoard(initialBoard);
}
```

Then renderBoard does this:

```
currentBoard = board;
```

Which causes both variables point to the same object. If you want them to be separated, then in renderBoard you should clone the object, instead of assigning it. Something along the lines of this if you use jQuery:

```
currentBoard = [];
$.extend(currentBoard, board);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need to buckle down and learn the language better.

Comment: @OnToTheNextOne Best way to learn is to make mistakes and correct them :)

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to how I should be handling the empty tile here?  I initialize the board with it as an empty string because that makes it easy to render.  But then it becomes an NaN in the currentBoard array later.  I had to add some awkward code to handle that such as the isNaN() check in the isSolved() function.

Comment: NaN is there because of the parseInts in swapTiles, you could change it to "parseInt(targetTileValue) || ''", then you will always have an empty string there.

Comment: For some reason I'm still having the same problem even when I change renderBoard to use $.extend() like you show above.  I'll let you know if I figure it out.

Comment: currentBoard = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(board));  This worked fine.